# Combine TXT files in a directory to one file with column added at end with for file name

Tags: powershell, copy

I have got a set of txt files in a directory that I want to merge together.

The contents of all the txt files are in the same format as follows:

```
IPAddress   Description             DNSDomain
---------   -----------             ---------
{192.168.1.2}   Microsoft Hyper-V   Network Adapter     
{192.168.1.30}  Microsoft Hyper-V   Network Adapter #2
```

I have the below code that combines all the txt files in to one txt file called all.txt.

```
copy *.txt all.txt
```

From this all.txt I can't see what lines came from what txt file. Any ideas on any bits of code that would add an extra column to the end txt file with the file name the rows come from?

Comment: If you hadn't mangled your data up with Format-Table / Out-String, you could have added a property for the server name in the script which generated those files. (And then put them all into one CSV). If at all possible, go back and edit that script so it outputs the right data - or easy to process data, instead of trying to take the hard-to-process output and work with that.

Comment: This is the powershell that generates the output file you see:

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName SERVERNAMEHERE | Format-Table -Property IPAddress, Description, DNSDomain | Out-File c:\temp\server.txt

Comment: There's no need to add a filename column. The entire content of `all.txt` comes from the last file enumerated by the wildcard pattern `*.txt`, because `copy *.txt all.txt` simply doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: Replace `Format-Table ... | Out-File ...` with `Select-Object PSComputerName, IPAddress, Description, DNSDomain | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\server.csv'`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments above, you've put the output of `Format-Table` into a text file. Note that `Format-Table` might be *visually* structured on screen, but is just lines of text. By doing that you have made it harder to work with the data.

If you just want a few properties from the results of the `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet, use `Select-Object` which (in the use given here) will effectively filter the data for just the properties you want.

Instead of writing text to a simple file, you can preserve the tabular nature of the data by writing to a structured file (i.e. CSV):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName SERVERNAMEHERE |
  Select-Object PSComputerName, IPAddress, Description, DNSDomain |
  Export-Csv 'C:\temp\server.csv'
```

Note that we were able to include the **PScomputerName** property in each line of data, effectively giving you the extra column of data you wanted.

So much for getting the raw data. One way you could read in all the CSV data and write it out again might look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv -Exclude all.csv |
    Foreach-Object {Import-Csv $_} |
    Export-Csv all.csv
```

Note that we exclude the output file in the initial cmdlet to avoid reading and writing form/to the same file endlessly.

If you don't have the luxury to collect the data again you'll need to spool the files together. Spooling files together is done with `Get-Content`, something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt -Exclude all.txt |
    Foreach-Object {Get-Content $_ -Raw} |
    Out-File all.txt
```

In your case, you wanted to suffix each line, which tricker as you need to process the files line-by-line:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem *.txt

foreach($file in $files) {
    $lines = Get-Content $file
    foreach($line in $lines) {
        "$line $($file.Name)" | Out-File all.txt -Append
    }
}
```